# How to set BadgeText in a chrome extension depending on a JSON response

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension where I have to set badge text depending on a JSON response which varies from url to url. The badge text will be equal to the length of the array returned by JSON response. I want the badge text to be updated as soon as the active tab loads a website. Presently, my code updates the badge text only after clicking on the extension icon. Here's my code:

*background.js*

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
tabUrl = tabs[0].url;

checkStatus(function(length){
  if(length>0){
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: 'blue' });
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
      path : "icons/icon2.png"
    });
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: length.toString() });
  } else {
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
      path : 
   "icons/icon1.png"
    });
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: "" });
  }
 });
});
});

function checkStatus(callbacks){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);//parsing the JSON response to javascript object

    length = myObj.length;
    callbacks(length);
    };
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://example.com/?url=" + tabUrl + "&type=json", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

I tried sending a message from `content-script`, script.js and then updating the badge text in the background.js on receiving it, via `chrome.runtime.onMessage` but it failed since I already had a message being sent from background.js to script.js.

Many extensions make use of badge text in this manner. Suggest some way to work this out.

*manifest.json*

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "foo",
  "description": "xyz",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon1",
    "default_title": "Title"
  },

  "web_accessible_resources": [
       "popup.html", "frame.html"
   ],

  "background": {
   "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "content_scripts": [
   {
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "matches": ["*://*/*"],
    "js": ["script.js"]
   }
  ],

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "webNavigation",
    "tabs",
    "https://foo.com/"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your manifest.json and relevant files I can only guess you include background.js in your popup.html which is wrong. See the documentation and 1) simply declare background page in manifest.json, 2) use chrome.tabs.onUpdated event, 3) specify tab id parameter in setIcon.

Comment: using `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` instead of `chrome.tabs.query` worked!

Comment: There is still one issue. If I return to a tab and even reload it, badge text doesn't get updated. Badge Text remains the same as was in the previous tab.

Comment: Use chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted event instead of chrome.tabs.onUpdated.

Comment: I updated my question with manifest.json and `chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted`. What happens now is every time a reload or load a tab, badge text gets updated, but not when I switch to another tab. I tried saving the data by `chrome.storage.local` and display badge text depending on the saved data, but on doing so, the extension didn't even work.

Comment: Well, that's why I mentioned point number 3)